# Converting large data with lat and long into X and Y?

Tags: python, convert, latitude-longitude, utm, pyproj

I have 9888562 records in dataframe and I would like to convert my lat, long to UTM x,y. according to my code, I have used pyproj package but because my data are too much it takes a long time and finally, it doesn't work. 
I wonder whether you know another way or package that I can use for my data?

```
def rule(row):
    p = Proj(proj='utm',zone=10,ellps='WGS84', preserve_units=False)
    x,y = p(row["LON"], row["LAT"])
    return pd.Series({"X": x , "Y": y})
My_data = My_data.merge(My_data.apply(rule, axis=1), left_index= True, right_index= True)
```

[image: My data is like this]

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? can you give a pair of input points and output returned?

Comment: Yes. I have tried my code for several rows and it works but when I try my code for large data(9888562 rows) it takes along time. I waited for 8 hours but it was running and I interrupted it.

Answer (score 7):

UPDATE:

After thinking about it, the most efficient method for you to transform the coordinates is probably to not use `apply` but to use the column array.

```py
from pyproj import Proj
pp = Proj(proj='utm',zone=10,ellps='WGS84', preserve_units=False)

xx, yy = pp(My_data["LON"].values, My_data["LAT"].values)
My_data["X"] = xx
My_data["Y"] = yy
```

Using `Transformer`

```py
from pyproj import Transformer

trans = Transformer.from_crs(
    "epsg:4326",
    "+proj=utm +zone=10 +ellps=WGS84",
    always_xy=True,
)
xx, yy = trans.transform(My_data["LON"].values, My_data["LAT"].values)
My_data["X"] = xx
My_data["Y"] = yy
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

This answer here is great: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/334276/144357

The solution below is for the purposes of understanding the root of the problem a bit better.

Your code in its current form re-constructs the `Proj` object with each iteration. This is a costly operation and is why the `pyproj.Transformer` object was created. It assists with repeated transformations because you don't have to re-create it each time (see: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/advanced_examples.html#repeated-transformations).

So, to avoid re-creating the `Proj` object, you can modify your code like so:

```py
from pyproj import Proj
from functools import partial

p = Proj(proj='utm',zone=10,ellps='WGS84', preserve_units=False)

def impartial_rule(row, proj):
    x,y = proj(row["LON"], row["LAT"])
    return pd.Series({"X": x , "Y": y})

rule = partial(impartial_rule, proj=p)
My_data = My_data.merge(My_data.apply(rule, axis=1), left_index= True, right_index= True)
```

This should improve your performance.

Here is the equivalent using the `pyproj.Transformer`:

```py
from pyproj import Transformer
from functools import partial

trans = Transformer.from_crs(
    "epsg:4326",
    "+proj=utm +zone=10 +ellps=WGS84",
    always_xy=True,
)

def impartial_rule(row, proj):
    x,y = proj(row["LON"], row["LAT"])
    return pd.Series({"X": x , "Y": y})

rule = partial(impartial_rule, proj=trans.transform)
My_data = My_data.merge(My_data.apply(rule, axis=1), left_index= True, right_index= True)
```

Hopefully this is helpful. Good luck!

Also, I would recommend reading this about `Proj`: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#proj-not-a-generic-latitude-longitude-to-projection-converter

Comment: Thank you for the update, this is much faster! However, I suggest using     `df.assign(X=xx)` and `df.assign(Y=yy)`. This will also prevent the [returning-a-view-versus-a-copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) warning

Answer (score 3):

You can directly use [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) or [GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/) but with 9888562 records It will take a long time to do (if you want a Progress bar during the pandas operations, you can use [tqdm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34365537):

[image])

1) With your solution and the first 4 points

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'LAT':[47.9767,47.9803,47.9801,47.9798], 'LON':[-122.2450,-122.2458,-122.2472,-122.2465]})
My_data = df.merge(df.apply(rule, axis=1), left_index= True, right_index= True)
print(My_data)
     LAT       LON              X             Y
0  47.9767 -122.2450  556344.793287  5.313986e+06
1  47.9803 -122.2458  556281.177583  5.314386e+06
2  47.9801 -122.2472  556176.922041  5.314363e+06
3  47.9798 -122.2465  556229.484294  5.314330e+06
```

2) With shapely

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
df['geometry'] = df.apply(lambda row: Point(row.LON, row.LAT), axis=1)
print(df)
    LAT       LON                 geometry
0  47.9767 -122.2450  POINT (-122.245 47.9767)
1  47.9803 -122.2458  POINT (-122.2458 47.9803)
2  47.9801 -122.2472  POINT (-122.2472 47.9801)
3  47.9798 -122.2465  POINT (-122.2465 47.9798)
# change the projection of points
from functools import partial
from shapely.ops import transform
import pyproj   
project = partial(
    pyproj.transform,
    pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326'), # source coordinate system
    pyproj.Proj('+proj=utm +zone=10 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs')) # destination coordinate system
sdf = df.copy()
sdf['project'] = sdf.geometry.apply(lambda row: transform(project,row))
print(sdf)
    LAT       LON                   geometry                  project
0  47.9767 -122.2450  POINT (-122.245 47.9767)   POINT (556344.7932874847 5313986.318933257)
1  47.9803 -122.2458  POINT (-122.2458 47.9803)  POINT (556281.1775833125 5314385.854768319)
2  47.9801 -122.2472  POINT (-122.2472 47.9801)  POINT (556176.9220411006 5314362.605105238)
3  47.9798 -122.2465  POINT (-122.2465 47.9798)  POINT (556229.4842943319 5314329.77191091)
```

3) Directly with GeoPandas

```
import geopandas as gpd
# change to GeoDataFrame
geodf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df)
geodf.crs= {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
# change the projection of geodf
geodf = geodf.to_crs("+proj=utm +zone=10 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_def")
print(geodf)
       LAT       LON                          geometry
0  47.9767 -122.2450  POINT (556344.7932874847 5313986.318933257)
1  47.9803 -122.2458  POINT (556281.1775833125 5314385.854768319)
2  47.9801 -122.2472  POINT (556176.9220411006 5314362.605105238)
3  47.9798 -122.2465  POINT (556229.4842943319 5314329.77191091)
```

4) If you want the X and Y values, it is easy

```
geodf["x"] = geodf.geometry.apply(lambda row:row.x)
geodf["y"] = geodf.geometry.apply(lambda row:row.y)
print(geodf)
     LAT     LON                      geometry                       x                    y
0  47.9767 -122.2450  POINT (556344.7932874847 5313986.318933257)  556344.793287  5.313986e+06
1  47.9803 -122.2458  POINT (556281.1775833125 5314385.854768319)  556281.177583  5.314386e+06
2  47.9801 -122.2472  POINT (556176.9220411006 5314362.605105238)  556176.922041  5.314363e+06
3  47.9798 -122.2465  POINT (556229.4842943319 5314329.77191091)   556229.484294  5.314330e+06
```