# Making a coordinate transformation on a csv file using pyproj?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, csv, pyproj

I mostly got my answer from this original posting: [How to reproject 500 CSV files efficiently and easily using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168081/how-to-reproject-500-csv-files-efficiently-and-easily-using-qgis)
and using the code from response 7 from blord-castillo.

My problem is that the code, I suspect, is from earlier versions and I am unclear how to update it for pyproj 2.4.1 and python 3.7.6. I'm using Spyder 4.0.1 in Anaconda. I only have one csv file, but I do not think that is really an issue.

I have a csv file with a list of long,lat and I want to make a coordinate transformation to another CRS and save the output to a new csv file with x,y.

I updated the script to my file and projections. Here:

```
import csv
import pyproj
from functools import partial
from os import listdir, path

#Define some constants at the top
#Obviously this could be rewritten as a class with these as parameters

lon = 'LONGITUDE' #name of longitude field in original files
lat = 'LATITUDE' #name of latitude field in original files
f_x = 'x' #name of new x value field in new projected files
f_y = 'y' #name of new y value field in new projected files
in_path = r'myinput' #input directory
out_path = r'myoutput' #output directory
input_projection = 'epsg:4326' #WGS84
output_projecton = 'epsg:3395' #World mercator

#Get CSVs to reproject from input path
files= [f for f in listdir(in_path) if f.endswith('.csv')]

#Define partial function for use later when reprojecting
project = partial(
    pyproj.transform,
    pyproj.Proj(init=input_projection),
    pyproj.Proj(init=output_projecton))

for csvfile in files:
    #open a writer, appending '_project' onto the base name
    with open(path.join(out_path, csvfile.replace('.csv','_project.csv')), 'wb') as w:
        #open the reader
        with open(path.join( in_path, csvfile), 'rb') as r:
            reader = csv.DictReader(r, dialect='excel')
            #Create new fieldnames list from reader
            # replacing lon and lat fields with x and y fields
            fn = [x for x in reader.fieldnames]
            fn[fn.index(lon)] = f_x
            fn[fn.index(lat)] = f_y
            writer = csv.DictWriter(w, fieldnames=fn)
            #Write the output
            writer.writeheader()
            for row in reader:
                x,y = (float(row[lon]), float(row[lat]))
                try:
                    #Add x,y keys and remove lon, lat keys
                    row[f_x], row[f_y] = project(x, y)
                    row.pop(lon, None)
                    row.pop(lat, None)
                    writer.writerow(row)
                except Exception as e:
                    #If coordinates are out of bounds, skip row and print the error
                    print (e)
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "file.py", line 43, in <module>
    fn = [x for x in reader.fieldnames]

  File "mypath\csv.py", line 98, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)

Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

I have tried to compare the current documentation to the code, but I am a novice here and not entirely sure what I need to change. I have already checked that everything works up to this point by adding a line "print (continue)" in a few places.

In your answers, please remember, novice here.

Comment: You are opening the file in binary mode with 'rb' (`with open(path.join( in_path, csvfile), 'rb') as r:`) and not in text mode (`with open(path.join( in_path, csvfile), 'rt')`or simply `with open(path.join( in_path, csvfile))` -> Error

Comment: Great! Thanks! Removing b did it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend either:

1. pandas and pyproj.Transforner for the most efficient method:

```py
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv(...)
```

Then see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/334307/144357

2. Use geopandas with the `.to_crs()` method.

https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projections.html

```py
import geopandas
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv(...)
gdf = df.set_geometry(geopandas.points_from_xy(df.LONGITUDE, df.LATITUDE), crs="EPSG:4326")
projected_df = gdf.to_crs("EPSG:3395")
df["x"] = projected_df.geometry.x
df["y"] = projected_df.geometry.y
df.to_csv(...)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark here as I am not able to reproduce the code you have provided at the moment.

The error suggests you should try to open the file in text mode. From the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) on the `open()` function:

> The first argument is a string containing the filename. The second
>   argument is another string containing a few characters describing the
>   way in which the file will be used. mode can be 'r' when the file will
>   only be read, 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same
>   name will be erased), and 'a' opens the file for appending; any data
>   written to the file is automatically added to the end. 'r+' opens the
>   file for both reading and writing. The mode argument is optional; 'r'
>   will be assumed if it’s omitted.
>
> On Windows, 'b' appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode, so
>   there are also modes like 'rb', 'wb', and 'r+b'. Python on Windows
>   makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line
>   characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data
>   is read or written. This behind-the-scenes modification to file data
>   is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll corrupt binary data like that
>   in JPEG or EXE files. Be very careful to use binary mode when reading
>   and writing such files. On Unix, it doesn’t hurt to append a 'b' to
>   the mode, so you can use it platform-independently for all binary
>   files.

Basically you are opening both files (`reader` and `writer`) in binary mode. You can test whether opening them in text mode will work. Simply change:

```py
with open(path.join(out_path, csvfile.replace('.csv','_project.csv')), 'wb') as w:
```

for

```py
with open(path.join(out_path, csvfile.replace('.csv','_project.csv')), 'w') as w:
```

and

```py
with open(path.join( in_path, csvfile), 'rb') as r:
```

for

```py
with open(path.join( in_path, csvfile), 'r') as r:
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Removing 'b' did it.

Comment: @lisa I'm glad it worked. Feel free to take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for future questions.